# Membership.CreateUser() in a Class Library

Tags: .net, class, asp.net-membership

I'm in the process of moving code out of `App_Code` into a class library.

I create users programmatically using `Membership.CreateUser`.

How can I continue to do this inside my class library where there's no access to the membership provider I have configured in `web.config`?

Comment: You have a class in your asp.net application and yet it does not have access to information in the web.config?  Is it in a folder with its own web.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a using directive to the `System.Web.Security` namespace in your class - this will give you direct access to the `Membership` class.

C#:

```
using System.Web.Security;
```

VB.NET:

```
Imports System.Web.Security
```

Comment: Can already access the membership class. Because inside the class library it can't read the web.config, it seems to use some default provider instead of the SQL Sever one I've configured in the web.config file.

Comment: @Chris - A class library will run under some context - it will have access to the configuration of the application it runs under.

Comment: Inside my class library, I will call:

`MembershipUser NewUser = Membership.CreateUser(userName, password, email, "no question", "no answer", true, out createStatus);`

with a password of "wonder123", this isn't acceptable by default (no non-alpha) but the app's web.config has this:

`<membership defaultProvider="MyProvider">
   <providers>
    <add 
    name="MyProvider" 
**minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" **
...    />
   </providers>
  </membership>`

So if its reading the above, it would accept "wonder123" as a password, instead I get createStatus.InvalidPassword.

Answer (score 4):

Before I show you how the code part works - you need to understand how the settings get loaded up in this kind of scenario.

When you have a Web Application which is going to load your `.dll` file - and that `.dll` file is going to access the `MembershipProvider` which the application has configured - you have to make a few assumptions.

1. The Web Application has a `MembershipProvider`
2. The Web Application provides settings for that `MembershipProvider` in its `Web.Config`
3. The Web Application loads your `.dll` correctly

Because your `.dll` file should be included in the Web Application's `/bin` directory, you should be able to rely on the *Web Application's configuration* rather than having to supply your own.

To do this, start with what Oded mentions in his answer - create a reference to `System.Web.Security` within your `.dll`'s code - then within that file you can do something like the following:

```
if (Membership.Provider != null) {
    Membership.Provider.CreateUser( ... );
} else {
    // Do something appropriate in a case where there is no Membership Provider
}
```

At this point - if the above doesn't work, it is likely because your Web Application doesn't have an appropriate provider configured.

**A note on *why* to do it this way...**

The reason you should let the Web Application provide the configuration is to comply with the principle of [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). The [`MembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) is an abstract class which provides default functionality - with very little implementation.

In other words - it defines that to manage members, you need to be able to perform operations such as `CreateUser()` and `GetAllUsers()`. It also says that you should be able to configure settings, such as specifying a `PasswordFormat` and determining whether or not each user `RequiresUniqueEmail`.

What it doesn't do is tell you where to store your User information. It leaves that up to the implementor (`System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider` or `YourNS.YourMembershipProvider`).

The Application which uses the `MembershipProvider` then determines what settings to provide and which implementation to use. In other words - it's the job of `YourNS.YourMembershipProvider` to specify how information is managed, but it is likely the Application who should determine what `ConnectionString` to use in its storage, etc.

So - following the pattern I outlined above allows you to provide three separate layers:

1. an application which will consume the `MembershipProvider`,
2. an assembly which provides the `MembershipProvider` implementation, and
3. an assembly which uses whichever `MembershipProvider` is configured - and does something with it on behalf of the application (*this is the layer you're describing in your post, I believe)

Notice that if you follow this pattern - you can now switch `MembershipProviders` at a later time *without having to alter either of the other layers* - because those layers rely on the base class of `MembershipProvider` - rather than relying on your specific implementation. This can be hugely valuable.

Comment: Glad it helped. :) I've had to do this a number of times in various projects - and I remember how frustrating it was the first few times, to figure out the moving parts.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by copying the whole web.config to my app.config. I was using a console application. I thought I had copied the necessary sections but until I copied everything, the data was not getting to database

Answer (score 0):

You can access it anywhere becouse the Membership class is a static representation of the current provider setted by the ASP.NET provider system.